# Where can I download Ubuntu 13.04 Beta release?

Tags: downloads, iso, 13.04, beta

I've heard that the Ubuntu 13.04 Beta release is out. If that's correct, where can I download it? When I look for it, all I find is the daily build, which is different from the Beta release, right? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[This link](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/RaringRingtail/TechnicalOverview#Download_the_Beta_1) features an overview of download links for 13.04 Beta 1:

> http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/13.04/beta-1/ (Ubuntu Cloud Server)
>      http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/13.04/ (Ubuntu Netboot)
>
> http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.04/beta-1/ (Kubuntu)
>      http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu-active/releases/13.04/beta-1/ (Kubuntu Active)
>      http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/13.04/beta-1/ (Lubuntu)
>
> http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/13.04/beta-1/ (Edubuntu DVD)
>      http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/13.04/beta-1/ (Ubuntu Studio)
>      http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/13.04/beta-1/ (Xubuntu)

Answer (score -1):

You can find all the daily build iso images here:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Comment: I already know where to find the daily builds. My question is, is the Beta release different from the daily build, and if so, where can I download the Beta release? Thanks for the help!

Comment: There isn't Ubuntu Beta yet.Beta release is April 4. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseSchedule

Comment: Actually the listed beta release was on the 14th of this month. As far as the beta iso's go, I don't think there is an official one. If you want a beta copy, then just get a daily build.

Comment: Only flavours (Edubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, UbuntuKylin,
Ubuntu Cloud, Ubuntu Studio and Xubuntu) had Beta 1.https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/TechnicalOverview  https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2013-March/001024.html

Comment: Thanks Novatillasku, I believe that answers my question. I look for the beta release this week.